# Magnetometer sensors reading in android studio application

Tags: java, android, magnetometer

How to get magnetometer readings in `x y z` coordinates in android application?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to retrieve sensor values :

```
public class MagnetometerActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    // Sensors & SensorManager
    private Sensor magnetometer;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    // Storage for Sensor readings
    private float[] mGeomagnetic = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get a reference to the SensorManager
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Get a reference to the magnetometer
        magnetometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        // Exit unless sensor are available
        if (null == magnetometer)
            finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Register for sensor updates

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Unregister all sensors
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // Acquire magnetometer event data

        else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mGeomagnetic, 0, 3);

        }

        // If we have readings from both sensors then
        // use the readings to compute the device's orientation
        // and then update the display.

        if (mGeomagnetic != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mx : "+mGeomagnetic[0]+" my : "+mGeomagnetic[1]+" mz : "+mGeomagnetic[2]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // N/A
    }
}
```

If you want the uncalibrated values of the magnetometer, you can use the [TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED) sensor type. Please find all the details of the sensors [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html).

Hope it helps !